# "В свое время" - выделяется ли запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация

Выделяется ли запятыми оборот "в свое время"? Например: "Я(,) в свое время(,) там бывал несколько раз".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, причин для выделения нет никаких.
Если автору важно подчеркнуть интонационное выделение, то возможно использование тире: "Я - в свое время - там бывал несколько раз", но это только для передачи разговорной речи в каких-то особых контекстах.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, так как нет никаких причин для её постановки.